# angular empty get response

Tags: json, angularjs

Having trouble with binding json response to angularjs variable. The endpoint returns proper json and I can see same response through chrome javascript console. The console also shows status as 200 but for the "$scope.values" it always returns "[object Object]". I know that there were similar questions that been asked but none of the answer is working with following code:

```
    $scope.values = [];
    $http({
        url: '/company/leaderboard/',
        method: "GET",
        params: {memberId: $state.params.memberId,
            startDate: '2013-01-01',
            endDate: '2014-02-14',
            }
    }).success(function (data, status) {

        $scope.values = data;
        console.log("test result" + $scope.values)
        }).error("error message");

}
```

And here is the json response that shows up correctly:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "activity":44,
         "day":"2014-02-14"
      },
      {
         "activity":12,
         "day":"2013-05-18"
      }
   ],
   "revision":20,
   "status":"OK"
}
```

Comment: hard to help without seeing sample of data and knowing what expectations are

Comment: how is your server Web API configured?

Comment: As for expectations at this point it would be nice just to have it assigned to $scope.values variable, then it will be processed as input for Highcharts series

Comment: Is `$scope.values` supposed to be your entire json response, or just the `data` array?

Comment: The reason it is logging "[object Object]" is because in the `console.log()` statement you are concatenating a String and an Object using the `+` operator. It calls `toString()` on the object to do that. Instead try this: `console.log("test result", $scope.values);` That might shed some light on what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data Json response contains one more element data in it.If you want to access the data element please give data.data.I have tried the same and it;s working for me.

BTW for naming conflicts,rename data to some other name.

```
$scope.values = [];
$http({
    url: '/company/leaderboard/',
    method: "GET",
    params: {memberId: $state.params.memberId,
        startDate: '2013-01-01',
        endDate: '2014-02-14',
        }
}).success(function (output, status) {

    $scope.values = output.data;
    console.log("test result" + $scope.values)
}).error("error message");
```